# HttpURLConnection: Is it necessary to call connect()?

Tags: java, connection, httpurlconnection

Many examples I've seen don't explicitly call `connect()`. Instead they just use `getInputStream()` or `getResponseCode()`.

I'm assuming all of these HttpURLConnection methods that require a connection just call `connect()` themselves?

Are there any cases where `connect()` must be explicitly called for an HttpURLConnection?

Comment: Why did you delete your [new CW question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792805/httpurlconnection-what-is-the-minimum-best-practice-implementation)? I found it a good question. I was busy typing a world class answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, there are no cases. It's implicitly executed on demand. It's even specified in the documentation. Here's an extract of the [`URLConnection#connect()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#connect--) javadoc:

> Operations that depend on being connected, like `getContentLength`, will implicitly perform the connection, if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

`connect()` is implied and automatically invoked when needed.