# send a JSON object from android to php server

Tags: php, android, json

I'm having a very bad time trying to figure out the error in my code to implement the connection between the android application and the php server.

The following is my php code at the server:

```
<?php 
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$request = json_decode($json, true);
$response = array();
print "PHP HERE!";
// check for required fields
if (isset($request['Year']) && isset($request['Month']) && isset($request['Day_of_month']) && isset($request['Day_of_week']) && isset($request['Hour']) && isset($request['Minute'])) {

    $Year= $request['Year'];
    $Month= $request['Month'];
    $Day_of_month= $request['Day_of_month'];
    $Day_of_week= $request['Day_of_week'];
    $Hour= $request['Hour'];
    $Minute= $request['Minute'];

    // include db connect class
    require_once 'db_connect.php';

    // connecting to db
    $db = new DB_CONNECT();

    // mysql inserting a new row
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO date VALUES('$Year','$Month','$Day_of_month','$Day_of_week','$Hour','$Minute')");

    $response["success"] = 1;
    echo json_encode($response);
    exit;
}
?>
```

And my client side code is the following:

```
// Making HTTP request
try {
    // Open connection to URL and perform POST request.
    URL url1 = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url1.openConnection();
    urlConnection.setDoOutput(true); // Set Http method to POST
    urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    urlConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0); // Use default chunk size

    // Write serialized JSON data to output stream.
    OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
    //OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
    //BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8"));
    writer.write(params.toString());
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();

    InputStream input = urlConnection.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
    //BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
    //        is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    String line;

    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        result.append(line);
    }
    jObj = new JSONObject(result.toString());
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
}

// return JSON String
return jObj;
```

Please any help is appreciated.

Comment: what error? what is or is not happening? what is the problem? Is the java or php code generating any exceptions?

Comment: Sorry for missing that. What I'm  getting in good functioning of the app, it is taking my input, and supposedly sending it. The problem is that I'm not catching that object at the server. I mean that the database remains unchanged.

Comment: 'writer.write(params.toString());'. We cannot see what params you send so we cannot check. You should check and echo much more in your php script and then see first in your android code what you get back. Now you know nothing.

Comment: ' urlConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0); '. Remove that line.

Comment: '  writer.write(params.toString());'. What is 'params'? It's no json is it?

Comment: @greenapps Thank you for your answer.

Comment: The params are List<NameValuePair>. I didn't include all the code because it has a lot of things that got nothing to do with the actual connection

Comment: But then it has everything to do with you NOT sending json. So why is it in the subject of your post?

Answer (score 0):

You are not openning connection

Just call

```
urlConnection.connect(); //to open coonection and than
OutputStream os = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
OutputStreamWriter osWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(os,
                        "UTF-8");
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(osWriter);
writer.write(params.toString());

writer.flush();
writer.close();
os.close();
```

Comment: you should not need to call `connect()`

Comment: @husseinhammoud it is done by `urlConnection.getInputStream()`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792705/httpurlconnection-is-it-necessary-to-call-connect